# Model do MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Olá! Estou começando a usar MongoDB com Mongoose no NodeJS e estou encontrando um comportamento estranho ao criar mesus Models no MongoDB. Exemplo:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_teste');

const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        first: String,
        last: String
    }
});

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

Este código deveria criar o Model "Person", mas quando executo um "show collections" no Mongo, via prompt, em meu DB "db_teste" aparece "People" em lugar de "Person". Também criei um Model "teste" e apareceu "testes" (com um "s" a mais").

O que está ocorrendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um comportamento padrão do Mongoose que define o nome do `collection` como sendo o plural do nome do `model`, por isso `person` virou `people` e `teste` virou `testes`.

Você pode sobrescrever este comportamento definindo manualmente o valor do `collection`:

```
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        first: String,
        last: String
    }
}, { collection: 'person' });
```

Perceba na última linha, em que foi definido o nome da `collection`.

Comment: Ok, funcionou perfeitamente. Gostaria de saber se também é possível desabilitar esse comportamento. Obrigado

Comment: Acredito que não, teria que procurar na documentação melhor. Eu particularmente nunca utilizei o Mongoose (nem conhecia até esta pergunta), então não sei te responder com certeza se é possível.

Comment: Dei uma lida na documentação e acho que não tem como desabilitar, pois no padrão do Mongoose o model tem um formato definido como `Mongoose#model(name, [schema], [collection], [skipInit])` e também pode ser setado o nome como `schema.set('collection', 'actor');`